# Python complex operation with dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the following dataframe:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,0],'B':[1,0,1,1,0],'C':[1,1,1,0,0],'D':[1,1,0,0,0],'E':[1,0,0,0,0]})
> print(df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  0  1  1  0
2  1  1  1  0  0
3  1  1  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0
```

I want to produce a new dataframe with same columns which does the following:

**for each cell puts 1, if all cells to the left in this row are equal to 1, and 0 otherwise.**

So the output for the given example should look like this:

```
> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,0],'B':[1,0,1,1,0],'C':[1,0,1,0,0],'D':[1,0,0,0,0],'E':[1,0,0,0,0]})
> print(df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  1  0  0
3  1  1  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0
```

I am looking for a generic code which can be replicated for all dataframes of all sizes as this one.

I did a google search and attempted to code it on my own, but did not get any satisfactory results.

Another example - a conversion on the row level would look like this:

1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1 -> 1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure `df` is a dict in your code?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please can you review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide?
Your question is not currently in a form that will get much of a response

Specifically you should edit your question to include the steps that you have tried so far and the problems you got with them.

Comment: I tried writing an IF formula for each column and it worked but the problem is that my dataframe is huge, so I am looking for a generic solution, applicable to a big df with 100+ columns - I am also sure that something better than IF exists in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can define a simple function to find the first index where 0 occurs, and return an array with 1's filled to that position.  Also need to account for rows with no zeros and send back all 1's.

```
def findOnes(x):
    res = np.zeros(len(x))
    fstZero = np.where(x==0)[0]
    if len(fstZero) == 0:
        return res+1
    return res[:np.min(fstZero)]=1
```

Then this function can be applied to the original `dataframe`.

```
dfNew = df.apply(findOnes, axis=1, result_type='broadcast')
```

Which will give the desired output:

```
print(dfNew)
    A   B   C   D   E
0   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   0
2   1   1   1   0   0
3   1   1   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0
```

So using your data above the full solution would look like

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def findOnes(x):
    res = np.zeros(len(x))
    fstZero = np.where(x==0)[0]
    if len(fstZero) == 0:
        return res+1
    return res[:np.min(fstZero)]=1

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,0],'B':[1,0,1,1,0],'C':[1,1,1,0,0],
                   'D':[1,1,0,0,0],'E':[1,0,0,0,0]})

dfNew = df.apply(findOnes, axis=1, result_type='broadcast')
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient method for large DataFrames, but it will do the trick for an arbitrary size.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,0],'B':[1,0,1,1,0],'C':[1,1,1,0,0],'D':[1,1,0,0,0],'E':[1,0,0,0,0]})

output = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    o = [1 for j in range(df.shape[1]) if all(df.iloc[i, :j+1] == 1)]
    output.append(o)

# Convert output to a DataFrame
output = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=df.columns)
output.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Check output

```
print(output)

     A    B    C    D    E
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
3  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Jtweeder’s answer is better